# Get two lowest values from a table with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ankaran</td>
        <td>101</td>
        <td>91</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ljubljana</td>
        <td>102</td>
        <td>213</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Celje</td>
        <td>103</td>
        <td>711</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Portorož</td>
        <td>104</td>
        <td>121</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to get the two lowest values from the last column ("Value") and color the td tags with these two values. What code can acomplish this?

I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnSelect").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        var values= new Array();
        $('tr').each(function () {
            var sorted = $(this).find('td:last').html();
            values.push(sorted);
        });
        console.log(values);
    });
});
```

I got the lowest value, but that is about as far as I got, also I dont think this is a robust solution

Comment: Did you tried it first?

Comment: you're asking for a logic/algorithmic solution, we only provide solutions to logic errors/programmatical errors, try something on your own first, that's what makes a programmer

Comment: I did, I edited the code above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, check the <kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ronency/JwP34/1/)</kbd>

Consider your HTML, here is my css & js solution:

**javascript**

```
var tds = $('td.value');
var arr = $.makeArray(tds);
arr.sort(function(a,b){
    return parseInt($(b).text()) - parseInt($(a).text());
});

$(arr[arr.length-2]).addClass('lowest');
$(arr[arr.length-1]).addClass('lowest');
```

**css**

```
td.lowest {background-color:lightgreen;}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var ok = $('table tr td:last-child').map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
}).get().sort(function (x, y) {
    return x - y
});

alert(ok[0] + ' - is the smallest');
alert(ok[1] + ' - is the 2nd smallest');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/263Ps/

Comment: It is a way to get the two lowest values, but the guy here wanted to get hold of their surrounding tds...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var map = {}, array = [];
var $tds = $('table tr').slice(1).find('td:last-child').each(function () {
    var value = +$(this).text();
    if (map[value]) {
        map[value].push(this);
    } else {
        map[value] = [this];
        array.push(value);
    }
})
array.sort(function(a1, a2){
    return a1 - a2;
});
$tds.filter(function () {
    return $.inArray(+$(this).text(), array) < 2;
}).css('color', 'red')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TvW9z/)

Answer (score 1):

```
var values = [],
    tds = $("table tr").find("td:last");

tds.each(function(){ 
    $(this).data("val",$(this).text());
    values.push(parseInt($(this).text()))
})
values.sort(function(x,y){return x > y});
tds.each(function(){
    if($(this).data("val") == values[0] || $(this).data("val") == values[1])
       $(this).css("color","red");
})
```

values[0] and values[1] will be smallest and second smallest values respectively.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:-

```
var values = $('td:last-child').sort(function(a, b) {
   return $(a).text() - $(b).text();
}).slice(0, 2).css('color', 'red').map(function() {
   return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

So, sort each `td:last-child` by its `text()` value (low to high), then use `slice()` to get the first two elements. Apply the `css()` to these elements, then use `map()` to return their `text()`, which will be assigned to `var values`

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/25x47/18/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'd go with spokey's sorting function and then extract the `.filter` function from Arun's answer, or simply a

`$(this).attr('style', 'color:red;')`

or whatever color you want, to highlight the cell, 
or if you wanted to highlight the entire row you could just go

`$(this).parent().attr('style', 'color:red;')`