# Jquery DataTables, highlight cell based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use DataTables to show a matrix of values pulled from a db with ajax. Now I want to highlight the cells in *each row* with the highest values:

```
10 | 12 | 54 | 1
4  | 92 | 11 | 40
9  | 12 | 99 | 98
```

In the above example, in row 1, 54 and 12, in row 2, 92 and 40 should be highlighted (background-color/class). I'm trying to mimick the conditional formatting of Excel.

Any ideas of how to approach the problem?

Comment: If the values are "static" and you are generating the page with PHP for instance, maybe you could do the processing on the server side and apply a certain class to cell you want to highlight?

Comment: that's an idea, but my plan is to dynamically make it possible to turn on/off, change to highlight the lowest, etc... And the data is retrieved as json-objects.

Comment: you can use the fnRowCallback to loop each row and do something like this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/21902642/2359055](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21902642/2359055)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use those two functions to navigate in the rows of your Table and then loop for all the TD's?

They directly extends DataTable plugin and are pretty easy to use. And they work on filtered tables too.

Functions:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnGetFilteredNodes = function ( oSettings )
{
        var anRows = [];
        for ( var i=0, iLen=oSettings.aiDisplay.length ; i<iLen ; i++ )
        {
                var nRow = oSettings.aoData[ oSettings.aiDisplay[i] ].nTr;
                anRows.push( nRow );
        }
        return anRows;
};

$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnGetTds  = function ( oSettings, mTr )
{
    var anTds = [];
    var anVisibleTds = [];
    var iCorrector = 0;
    var nTd, iColumn, iColumns;

    /* Take either a TR node or aoData index as the mTr property */
    var iRow = (typeof mTr == 'object') ?
        oSettings.oApi._fnNodeToDataIndex(oSettings, mTr) : mTr;
    var nTr = oSettings.aoData[iRow].nTr;

    /* Get an array of the visible TD elements */
    for ( iColumn=0, iColumns=nTr.childNodes.length ; iColumn<iColumns ; iColumn++ )
    {
        nTd = nTr.childNodes[iColumn];
        if ( nTd.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "TD" )
        {
            anVisibleTds.push( nTd );
        }
    }

    /* Construct and array of the combined elements */
    for ( iColumn=0, iColumns=oSettings.aoColumns.length ; iColumn<iColumns ; iColumn++ )
    {
        if ( oSettings.aoColumns[iColumn].bVisible )
        {
            anTds.push( anVisibleTds[iColumn-iCorrector] );
        }
        else
        {
            anTds.push( oSettings.aoData[iRow]._anHidden[iColumn] );
            iCorrector++;
        }
    }

    return anTds;
};
```

Use:

```
var nHidden=oTable.fnGetFilteredNodes();// Get filtered nodes
for(var i=0; i<nHidden.length; i++){
    $(oTable.fnGetTds(nHidden[i], 0)[0]) //etc... process TD's values 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you retrieve or make those rows into Arrays then you could do something like:

```
$.post('wherever.php', function(r){
  var eachRow = [];
  $.each(r, function(){
    eachRow.push(r.sort(function(a, b){return b-a;}).slice(-2));
  });
  $('#table tr').each(function(i, e){
    if($.inArray($(e).text(), eachRow[i])){
      $(e).addClass('highlight');
      // have .highlight{border:#ff0 solid 1px;} or whatever in CSS
    }
  });
});
```